# How to use string resources in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I have the following `strings.xml` resource file:

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- basic string -->
    <string name="app_name">My Playground</string>

    <!-- basic string with an argument -->
    <string name="greeting">Hello %!</string>

    <!-- plural string -->
    <plurals name="likes">
        <item quantity="one">%1d like</item>
        <item quantity="other">%1d likes</item>
    </plurals>

    <!-- string array -->
    <string-array name="planets">
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

How can I use these resources in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 116):

There's [androidx.compose.ui.res](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary) package containing functions for loading string resources as well as other resource types.

#### string

You can get a string using [`stringResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#stringresource) function, for example:

```kotlin
...
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource

@Composable
fun StringResourceExample() {
  Text(
    // a string without arguments
    text = stringResource(R.string.app_name)
  )

  Text(
    // a string with arguments
    text = stringResource(R.string.greeting, "World")
  )
}
```

#### string array

Can be obtained using [`stringArrayResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#stringarrayresource) function:

```kotlin
val planets = stringArrayResource(R.array.planets_array)
```

#### plural (quantity string)

As of compose `1.0.0-alpha10` there's no build-in function for obtaining a plural resource, but you can get the android context via [LocalContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#localcontext) and use it the same way as you do it in a view-based app. Even better if you create your own function similar to other *resource functions* (like [Jetcaster](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetcaster) compose sample does for example):

```kotlin
// PluralResources.kt

package com.myapp.util

import androidx.annotation.PluralsRes
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext

@Composable
fun quantityStringResource(@PluralsRes id: Int, quantity: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): String {
    return LocalContext.current.resources.getQuantityString(id, quantity, *formatArgs)
}
```

so you can use it the same way:

```kotlin
val likes = quantityStringResource(R.plurals.likes, 10, 10)
```

#### a note about recomposition

As you know, in compose a composable function might be re-executed up to hundreds of times per second during [recomposition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition). If the string you build isn't trivial and requires some calculation, it's better to [remember](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-remember-to-store-immutable-values) the calculation result, so it won't be re-executed on each recomposition. For example:

```kotlin
...

import androidx.compose.runtime.remember

@Composable
fun BirthdayDateComposable(username: String, dateMillis: Long) {
  // formatDate() function will be executed only if dateMillis value 
  // is changed, otherwise the remembered value will be used
  val dateStr = remember(dateMillis) {
    formatDate(dateMillis)
  }

  Text(
    text = stringResource(R.string.birthday_date, dateStr)
  )
}
```

Comment: Regarding recomposition, are you sure `remember` would be needed in this example? The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition) suggests that a composable function is not recomposed if its parameters stay the same: "By skipping all functions or lambdas that don't have changed parameters, Compose can recompose efficiently."

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.myString)
```

Comment: I'm still getting issues with the strings even after importing. I'm using a multimodule project.

        Text(
           text = stringResource(id = R.strings.welcome_text)
        )

Answer (score 4):

This is now supported as of compose `1.2.0-alpha06`:

```
val likes = pluralStringResource(R.plurals.likes, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Can you share how you defined string in plurals.xml ?

Comment: @Wafi_ck I put my plurals in strings.xml, in exactly the same syntax as in the original question.

Comment: Now it's released in 1.2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in composable:

```
LocalContext.current.getResources().getIdentifier()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is slowly making its way into Compose Multiplatform as well.

If you put the file at `composeResources/values/strings.xml`, a `Res` object will be generated automatically, which allows navigating like:

```kotlin
val string1: String = stringResource(Res.string.app_name)
val string2: String = stringResource(Res.string.greeting, "World")
val string3: List<String> = stringArrayResource(Res.string.planets)
```

The package for those functions is `org.jetbrains.compose.resources`.

The benefit of doing it this way is that the same code then works for Desktop, Web, etc. I was testing this out on Web.

The downside of doing it this way is that plural support seems to be missing still. :(